# Built in closet drawers falling off track

Tags: closet, drawers

I have built in closets in my daughters room in our new home and the bottom 2 drawers are consistently falling off the track.  I suspect that the left and right walls of the drawer are flaring out making the runners too wide for the drawers to catch (forgive me if I'm using the wrong words to describe these things).

Pictures below including a wooden support they built in to allow the drawers to not hit the side of the closet when they open.

Can anyone please offer me any advice or suggestions on how to potentially get this issue resolved?  Thank you in advance!

[image: Drawers after opening, have fallen off runners]

[image: Closet with drawers, before opening bottom 2]

[image: Closer view of wooden support on left]

[image: Closeup of wooden support]

[image: Screws on other side holding wooden support to drawers]

[image: Picture of the track]

[image: Picture of the runner]

Comment: Can you pull out one of the drawers and take a picture showing what kind of tracks/runners these drawers are on?

Comment: I would remove all the drawers and inspect the drawer slides to make sure that they are securely attached to the drawer and to the cabinet. Then measure the inside of the cabinet at the top drawer and the bottom drawer and you'll know if the cabinet is pulling apart.

Comment: Yep. Might be as simple as tightening things up and adding washers to move the glides outboard.

Comment: @CactusCake I added the pictures.  Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose I should have mentioned this in my original post but I did tighten the screws on all the drawers before I posted this.  The problem, unfortunately, is not that the drawers are loose (they are solid).  It is that the runners that the drawer attaches to are slightly too wide (seemingly especially at the front) so that when I pull the drawer out they slip off of them

Comment: @isherwood adding some washers is an interesting idea, thanks, I will look into that

Comment: Yep, adding some washers between the rails and the drawers and/or between the rails and the frame should make everything fit a little more snug.

Comment: Adding washers as suggested near the front should work, you may find the screw won't be as secure. There's plenty of other holes in the runners that you can use to add another screw just drill a pilot hole and it should tighten up.

Comment: The washers worked like a charm thank you all so much!

Comment: I have some bookshelves that are very similar and indeed the sides were flaring.  My solution to that was some all-thread and some t-nuts.  I drilled holes on either side all the way through, put the t-nuts on the outside and pulled them together with the all-thread.  If the washer idea eventually fails, you might consider that as well.